# How to run concurrent ajax.jquery's

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have found out that ajax/jquerys' are not run concurrently (by default) because it can potentially corrupt the session state.  I have read of a work-around for this but it means converting my web form app to web mvc4.  Before I attempt this I have been looking around to see if there is a workaround for this. I have not tried disabling the sessionstate (yet) in my web config file as I use session state to manage logins and logouts.  Has any come across this before and are there work-arounds?

thanks

Comment: Given all the other benefits, I would suggest moving to MVC 4 anyway.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Hi, possibly.  But I looked into using MVC before and apart from forcing the developer to seperate logic from data from presentation which incidentally i always did before using web forms (and do not need the extra dev time to use MVC4 (which Microsoft says it would do so) I could not see any other benefits.  this is why I am loathed to move to MVC. But I am open to argument :)

Comment: Separation is only one good thing to come from MVC. The ease of creating strongly typed views, and even complete editor views, using just the wizards made it worthwhile. Also the seamless addition of REST services and total control over css and JS bundling/minification are winners for me. Getting used to the inline syntax is not that bad and I have not looked back since.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Hi, thanks for your thoughts.  I am not a big fan of wizards as I it dumbs down your programming skills. However, the rest of what you said sounded pretty cool. Maybe I should take another look on that basis then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer i prefer.  Whilst I found you could spawn your server process onto a different thread within the [web method] and thus return control immediately to the client. You could then implement a 2nd [web method] to check on progress (or abort by setting shared variable).  However, i did not like the idea of a thread being potentially let lose into the wilderness..!  Instead i found that setting this declaration into the @Page directive works for me..

```
EnableSessionState="ReadOnly"
```

Any feedback to correct me would be intuitive...